# How to do asynchornous post requests from django to external server?

Tags: python, django

Currently I am using requests for sending get or post request. But I need to send a asynchronous post request. Lets say I have three block in a task :

```
def funct():

    ###########
    # Section 1
    ###########
    print("First Sectiojn")
    ###########
    # Section 2
    ###########
    requests.post(url,data)
    ###########
    # Section 3
    ###########
    print("Third Section")
```

I just want to send the post requests in section 2 after that without waiting for the response I want to execute section 3. Please suggest me a good library or way.
Thanks in advance.